# 'A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.' at django 1.8.11

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, server, django-rest-framework

I updated my django from 1.7 to 1.8 and my server isn't running anymore.

What I did:

> - Tried to install python 3.6: nothing happened after I run the installer.
> - Uninstalled Django 1.7 and installed 1.9. Unfortunately this version brings me trouble (server didn't even starts).
> - Uninstalled 1.9 and installed 1.8. Now it's getting this error.

I'm on a macOS Sierra. 10.12.3. My python version is 2.7.

I need version 1.8 of Django in order to use the 'from rest_framwork.view import APIView'

Can someone help me?

Here's the log:

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    April 09, 2017 - 01:35:43
    Django version 1.8.18, using settings 'connectedin.settings'
    Starting development server at http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
        return self.application(environ, start_response)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
        response = self.get_response(request)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 207, in get_response
        return debug.technical_500_response(request, *sys.exc_info(), status_code=400)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/views/debug.py", line 97, in technical_500_response
        html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/views/debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
        return t.render(c)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 202, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
        bit = self.render_node(node, context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
        return node.render(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 329, in render
        return nodelist.render(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
        bit = self.render_node(node, context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
        return node.render(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py", line 89, in render
        output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 648, in resolve
        obj = self.var.resolve(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 789, in resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 849, in _resolve_lookup
        current = current()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/http/request.py", line 152, in build_absolute_uri
        host=self.get_host(),
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.18-py2.7.egg/django/http/request.py", line 102, in get_host
        raise DisallowedHost(msg)
    DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.0.101:8000'. You may need to add u'192.168.0.101' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
    [09/Apr/2017 01:35:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: [Why is *Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

This behavior changed between django 1.7] and django 1.8

[From 1.7 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> When DEBUG is True or when running tests, host validation is disabled;
>   any host will be accepted. Thus it’s usually only necessary to set it
>   in production.

[From 1.8 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated
>   against ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']

You need to add this IP address to this setting

Something on the lines of:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.101', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```